# Can't enable Developer Mode on Nexus 7 2013 with tapping the Build Number

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-options

I am trying to root Nexus 7 2013 and for the purpuse I need to enable USB debugging. As instructed from multiple resources, to **enable developer mode** one needs to **tap the build number 7 times**. Did that, plenty of times, but nothing happens.

I saw [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223748/android-4-2-developer-settings-still-unavailable) on the matter, where the case appeared to be that there were multiple users, but in my case there is just one user on the tablet.

About info picture: http://prntscr.com/rmo70x

Comment: Please give [this solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206783) a try

Comment: I don't know if you missed steps following the [official process](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/runningapp.html)

Comment: Just fyi this link is 404

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the tablet had installed **Family Link**. Once I removed the account from Family Link, tapping the build option worked.