# New method for enabling Developer Options in Android 13?

Tags: google-pixel, developer-options, android-13

I'm on a Pixel 6a with an OTA release of Android 13 stable. I had Developer Options with 13a beta 4 before I upgraded to a stable release, but now the menu option is no longer visible.

I tried tapping "build number", but it does not respond to touch interaction (no focus, feedback, etc.). Tapping it 7 times does nothing.

Is there a new way to enable Developer Options in Android 13 stable, or am I experiencing a bug?

Comment: When I tap the Build number on Android 13 (stable, Pixel4a) I get the toast that I am already a developer. I am using Settings -> About this phone -> Build number (last entry just below "send feedback"). As workaround you could try to get into developer options as described here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/206783/2241

Comment: Thanks @Robert, it looks like it just needed a restart. Very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my pixel 6a required a restart, now that I have power cycled it, the "build number" box has focus and responded to touch. 7 taps got me to developer options as expected.