# Unable to activate Developer Options on Samsung

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s, usb-debugging, bugs, developer-options

A quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694011/unable-to-activate-developer-options-on-my-android-phone):

> I have tried everything and am unable to activate the developer
> options on my Sasmung Galaxy S7 Edge with Android 8.0. Whenever I tap
> the build number repeatedly, it says that the developer mode has
> already been enabled. I can confirm however, that this is not the
> case:
>
> 1. The "Developer Options" menu does not appear in my settings
> 2. Even when using the search, these settings do not appear
> 3. Some users used third party apps like "ActivityLauncher" to manually search the com.settings.Settings.$DeveloperOptions activity.
>    I have tried this method multiple times with different apps, it doesnt
>    work. Trying to open an activity that requires developer mode gives me
>    an error as well.
> 4. Tried restarting the phone multiple times, closing all tabs, clearing the "settings"-App cache and data. Nothing works.
>
> I am at a loss right now... I really want to avoid resetting to
> factory mode because my phone has a ton of data stored on it. Any
> ideas on how I could solve this?

This was also true for my S8, Android 9. Though, every time it says "You are _ steps away from being a developer..." and then asks me to put in the password and then says "Developer mode has been turned on." I can repeat this many times and it will ask me for the password every time and say the same things every time and the developer options are still not there. I am equally at a loss to the OP and I'm equally unhappy about the current only solution of a factory reset. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-enabling Developer Options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205856/re-enabling-developer-options)

Comment: Try this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.developer.options

Comment: @Robert I am looking for a solution not a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried to enter Developer Settings and then disable them from within? Sometimes it is possible to activate Developer options the regular way.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. See my answer if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason it was for me: I use an internet filter called NetSpark (https://www.netsparkmobile.com/en/) which disables Developer Options as a security measure to prevent workarounds or uninstallations. It is a matter of enabling this in the Netspark settings.